# javascript singleton using arguments

Tags: javascript, module, singleton

I have the following pattern however I'd like to know if I am thinking about this the right way.  Do I need to assign the arguments to `this`?  Is there anything you would do differently?

```
var myFunction = (function() 
{
    function privateCheck(a,b) 
    { 
        console.log(a+b);
    }
    return 
    {
        init: function(x,y) 
        {
            privateCheck(x,y);
        }
    }
})();

myFunction.init(3,4);
myFunction.init(4,5);
```

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Can you explain what you mean by "assign the arguments to `this`?" Also, `myFunction` is a what most people would call a module, so I would give it name that suggests it is an object/module.

Comment: Thanks @acbabis.  What I meant was assigning the vales to the object so I don't have to pass it into the privateCheck function.

Comment: Assigning the arguments to `this` would actually make things more complicated. You'd have to call "privateCheck" differently.

Answer (score 3):

Your anonymous, immediately-invoked function will always return `undefined`. Your `return` statement trips over a common issue:

```
return { // <--- curly brace MUST be here
    init: function(x,y) 
    {
        privateCheck(x,y);
    }
}
```

Other than that it should be OK, though there's not much context.

*edit* the issue has to do with the often-weird rules about "semicolon insertion". In this particular case, like a handful of others, the language sees a newline after that `return` and assumes you just forgot the semicolon.

Comment: What difference does the placement of the curly braces make? I have on on the next line.

Comment: @KingKongFrog Try it :)  It's a weird corner of JavaScript syntax. It assumes that you forgot a semicolon after `return` in this particular case.

Comment: @KingKongFrog http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi